# Can't install Gnome on debian

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome3, i3

I've been trying to install Gnome on my Debian, I used i3wm previously, and I wanted to install Gnome for some demonstration purpose. I tried the command

```
sudo apt-get install gnome
```

And while installing, I was given an error while unpacking LibreOffice.

[image]

How can I resolve this?
I have even tried fixing broken installs using the command

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

But still, it gives the same error as stated above.

Comment: Please repost the output of your command in plain text (between the {} tags).

Comment: For some demonstration purpose it might work well enough with a live or persistent live system, and there is a current Debian live iso file with Gnome, that you can find via [this link](https://www.debian.org/CD/live/). Try it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LibreOffice packages in Debian conflict with the OpenOffice packages you currently have installed. If you want to install GNOME 3, you’ll need to remove the OpenOffice packages:

```
sudo apt purge openoffice\*
```

You will then be able to install GNOME:

```
sudo apt install gnome
```